# Can not link JS and CSS to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, bash, flask

I run flask on my Mac and try to connect the js and css to my html using the following code. When I inspect the element, it seem like the directory is complete correct but the css and js do not have effect on my html Please help !:

```
    <!-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta -->
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width" name="viewport"/>

    <!-- Script for using MathJax -->
    <script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>

    <!-- Link to own style sheet -->
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <!-- app's own JavaScript -->
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='scripts.js') }}"></script>

    <title>Corporate Finance Assistant: {% block title %}{% endblock %} </title>

</head>
```

[image: File window]

Comment: check your network tab and see if the URLs actually created by the script are correct. It will show you what path the browser is trying to download the scripts from

Comment: What does your console say?

Comment: The console show no error at all and this is what I get in the inspect element: <link href="/static/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/> and when I click on static/styles.css I get back the css file I wrote

Comment: That would indicate your files are correctly linked then but the code in your files isn't doing what you intend.

Comment: Could you share the specific CSS and HTML you want to style?